# MathJax Square root not properly displayed

Tags: html, mathjax, square-root

I'm using Mathjax to create complex mathematical formula. There's a problem regarding the square root. It appers that the slanted line is small and does not touch with the upper line. Does anyone know why this happened? Do I need to change the font?

Example of the formula: 
`\[t = {D\sqrt{CP_d \over f_pdE} }\]`

[image: Image of the formula]

[image: error message]

I've just realized about the error message in the console log.

Comment: I've seen this happen when zooming in via the browser.

Comment: @RobMoll But I didn't do any zoom in or zoom out. I've tried with different screen resolutions.Still no changes.

Comment: Please post a sample.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger what sample may I ask? The one that i showed in the question is the result I get when display the webpage.

Comment: @fatinamirah without a live sample, there is no way to debug the problem. From the looks of it, the fonts are not loading.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Hi Sir. I've already edit the question. It looks like the font is not found?

Comment: It looks like you are using a local copy of MathJax's `tex-mml-chtml` combined component, but may not have installed it properly.  Can you say how you installed it?  I suspect you only copied the `tex-mml-chtml.js` file, but didn't install the other required resources, like the fonts.